# Largest current merchants accepting Bitcoin?

Tags: merchants, commerce

I am writing some rants about the use of Bitcoin, and would like to sum it up by naming some spearpoint examples of companies and service providers that use Bitcoin. Either solely or side-by-side with conventional currency.

But the few lists I came across were either hopelessly outdated or simply false.

Can anyone name me some of the top busters using Bitcoin ? Or maybe some good creative examples of Bitcoin use ?

And please not the Alpaca Socks site. I need some fresh examples to shake off a bit of the dust and make the article seem current.

Comment: The Bitcoin Trader lists top 10 sites that accept Bitcoin donations according to their Alexa rating - http://www.thebitcointrader.com/2011/12/bitcoin-bounty-ladder.html . But as those are donations rather than payments, I guess this is mostly a side-note on the major players that have anything to do with Bitcoins.

Comment: A not necessarily up to date list - https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Business_and_organizations_that_%22also_accept_Bitcoin%22,_but_do_not_revolve_around_Bitcoin

Comment: I just came by this question and think it is too localised. There is no specific timeframe listed, so the answer to the question is likely to change. No metric is specified for what defines a big merchant - is it the trade volume, income, number of people employed and so forth. Voting to close.

Comment: You are right, its a bit fluent question of mine, I was just trying to get hold of some "proof of concept" case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The Bitcoin wiki](https://en.bitcoin.it/) contains [a rather large list of companies that accept Bitcons](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Trade). You can also add yourself to it once you started accepting Bitcoins.

The truth is Bitcoin is still in it's early days; soon it will be much easier to accept them.

Answer (score 2):

One service provider that accepts bitcoins is NoTex.ch @ https://notex.ch: It's a browser based editor, that accepts donations - the donate button has been created using BitPay - or you can buy the full fledged offline version using a customized and *very* simple to use checkout process, which has been implemented using Blockchain.info's [developer API](http://blockchain.info/api/api_receive):

- Step 1) Enter your e-mail address,
- Step 2) Scan the shown QR code for the actual transaction &
- Step 3) receive the download link (within ca. *one* minute!).

Implementation details:

One interesting point of the transaction is that it's fully anonymous, that means NoTex.ch does not see from which bitcoin address the money has been sent. This is possible because Blockchain.info offers this great service, which *mixes* all coins being transacted to diminish tracing possibilities (more details can be found in Blockchain.info's API section).

Another effect of this *mixing* is that the customer is *not* required to wait 10 minutes for the actual BTC transaction to go through: Given that NoTex.ch trusts Blockchain.info, which sends *immediately* a notification upon a transaction to a target address, upon which NoTex.ch sends the corresponding email to the customer. This 3-way communication/transaction is usually done within a minute (if Blockchain.info's mixing bag is sufficiently full).